# Java/Android read and store url.openStream into a raw memory stream

Tags: java, android, bitmapfactory

Imagine I am reading a big JPG file at 3mb. When unrolled as bitmap, it takes even more memory crashing my test phones. Therefore I first need to use `BitmapFactory.inJustDecodeBounds` + `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`. I then need to set sample size with a new `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` ... However, that design results in two downloads which is not acceptable (yet what most seem to use)

Is there a pure Java (I guess I could store to disk as well which might be better) that can store all the bytes... And which can be read from two times? (i.e. where I can reset position to beginning without clearing content, but just simply to have it reread again from the startt)

Comment: If you are able to store the bytes to a file you could then use FileInputStream to read/stream the bytes multiple times.

Comment: I will do that. Just surprised if there's no memory stream that allows multiple reads. (My background is not Java)